# Syslog not forwarding remote messages

Tags: c++, c, logging, syslog, yocto

I configured /etc/syslog.conf with below configuration

```
*.* @10.10.10.2:514
*.* @@10.10.10.2:514
```

and logged through below code

```
openlog("Test-Msg", LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL0);
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
    syslog(LOG_ALERT, "My msg %d", i);
    std::cout<<"-------------Writing Syslog "<<i<<"\n";
}

closelog();
```

but its not forwarding to remote server. instead of that it creates a file "@10.10.10.2:514" & "@@10.10.10.2:514" and logging all the message there.

Tested with wireshark, no messages are forwarded to remote system.

I am using yocto platform and busybox 1.22 syslog implementation.

**Update**

In yocto I saw one more configuration file /etc/syslog-startup.conf and there I configured

```
DESTINATION=remote  # log destinations (buffer file remote)
REMOTE=10.10.10.2:514          # where to log (syslog remote)
```

Now its started forwarding all the messages, but as per the linux manuals syslog conf must support `*.=alert @<host:port>` filter. If I have to use the above configuration how can I apply the filters?

Comment: Double-check which syslog implementation you're using...

Answer (score 2):

By default Yocto-based systems use Busybox to provide minimal versions of many basic tools. syslog is one of those tools. This is a quote from Busybox documentation:

> Note that this version of syslogd ignores /etc/syslog.conf.

To get full syslog functionality you'd have to include a more complete implementation on your image. There are several options in meta-openembedded, [rsyslog in meta-oe](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/845/)  is probably a good default choice.

Comment: Thanks @jku I added an invalid entry in the syslog.conf and I can see its crashing when I try to restart. So I think syslogd is reading the configuration file and trying to parse it

Comment: Well, there seems to be _limited_ support if a specific build configuration is enabled: https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/docs/syslog.conf.txt -- you'd have read the source to be sure but I'm willing to bet your syntax is not supported

Comment: @GilsonPJ You need to include rsyslog or syslog-ng in your image, they support remote logging. The syslogd in busybox does not support logging to a remote machine.

Comment: @nos as per the linux manual https://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf syslod must support this feature right? why busybox implementation is different? They are free to implement their own way, but how can they avoid a common feature?

Comment: That man page is not for the busybox syslogd implementation. It appears that busybox syslogd can do remote logging with the -R argument though if the  FEATURE_REMOTE_LOG is enabled when building busybox, as shown at https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html. Make sure you know what syslogd implementation you actually are running though - maybe you run something completely different.

Comment: Is it possible to do the upgrade by simple install rsyslog or syslog-ng just above the busybox (without reinstall busybox/) ? (I know this is old post, but find it useful)

Answer (score 0):

I would first use logger (tool incluided in busybox) to ensure that your syslog configuration is correct.
If the messages are sent well by this method, then we can investigate the code.

```
logger [OPTIONS] [MESSAGE]

Write MESSAGE to the system log. If MESSAGE is omitted, log stdin.

Options:

        -s      Log to stderr as well as the system log
        -t TAG  Log using the specified tag (defaults to user name)
        -p PRIO Priority (numeric or facility.level pair)
```

Comment: logger works fine. Tested using logger as well as a custom application

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking into this. busybox supports remote logging, but it seems to forward all the messages. There is no support for filtering combined with remote logging. I installed rsyslog on the image to solve this.

I also found out that rsyslog does not rotate files out of the box. Logrotate was installed as dependency but there is no cron daemon running. I had to install cronie and configure cronie, logrotate and rsyslog.